# Retrieve filename from a web folder

Tags: android, file, url, download

I am using `AsyncTask` to download a file from a web folder. However, the name of the file will be different every time.

Is there a way to get the name of the file in a web folder? (There will be only 1 file in that folder at a given time).

`http://www.example.com/myfolder/myfile_1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the ApacheURLLister (I didn't tested it but it may work):

```
URL url;
    List serverDir = null;

    try {
        url = new URL("http://www.abc.com/myfolder/");           
        ApacheURLLister lister = new ApacheURLLister();         
        serverDir = lister.listAll(url);
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("ERROR ON GETTING FILE","Error is " +e);
    }
    System.out.println(serverDir);
    return serverDir;
```